# C# Application - this.show() and this.hide() causing app to hang

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

I have a `C# app` which I want to run from a tray icon.  Basically it shouldn't show in the taskbar when minimised but when the tray icon is double clicked the app window should show as normal.

To achieve this I am using `this.Show()` and `this.Hide()` which do exactly what I want.  The issue I'm having is that for some users when the application is shown, the form appears but none of the UI is drawn correctly and whatever was open below the form shows through.  The form becomes totally unresponsive but I can still get it to hide and show by double clicking the tray icon...

If I take the `.Show()` and `.Hide()` away the application runs with no issues for the users.

I am doing all the UI on the main thread and checking `InvokeRequired` to be double sure as I do have a `worker thread` but can't fix this issue.  Another point is that it doesn't happen all the time and typically only happens after the user's machine has been idle for some time.

I'd really appreciate any help on this.  The machines are WinXP using `.NET 3.5` and `VS2008`

Comment: Can you check your apps memory usage before and after the idle time (at the time the app freezes)? Observe the memory usage of your app during usage too, does it increase frequently during usage? I know it is not an answer, hence the comment, but checking memroy in task manager maybe a step in the right direction to detect any possible memory leaks. Usualy apps freeze due to memory issues or off course, blocked threads. If you memory is all perfect, maybe the GC dumps some of the Thread's resources after some idle time which could lead to a corrupted thread when coming back? Just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When are you calling this.Show and this.Hide ?

Can you compare or try the method detailed at   http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3336751/C-Tip-Placing-Your-C-Application-in-the-System-Tray.htm

If this is not done correctly, then I think you can get into a situation where the O/S is confused about a forms state and, for example, may think the form is already shown and hence does not redraw it fully.

Comment: I was doing this although i believe you may have pointed me in the right direction.  I have discoved another location where Hide() is called which could lead to two calls being made with no Show() in between.  I'm going to release this to the users now and see if it resolves the issue.